# FTP users created in cPanel cannot log in

Tags: ftp, cpanel

I feel like an absolute numpty asking this question, but I've struggled with it for literally years and I still have no idea what the answer is.

Basically I have never been able to log in with a new user that I've created in cPanel > FTP Accounts. This is consistent across several different domains and several different hosts, so presumably the issue is me.

Only I just go ahead and add a new user, then try and log in with the given information:

```
Host: ftp.domain.com
User: account@domain.com
Port: 21
Protocol: FTP
Encryption: Use explicit FTP over TLS if available
```

I've tried using SFTP; using plain FTP; using Filezilla, CoreFTP and Dreamweaver; setting the start folder as /public_html and /account; downloading and importing the config files that cPanel generates.

I have never had this work for me, not even once. Usually I just end up using the default FTP account, which is why I've never found an answer to this issue.

The errors are always along the lines of:

```
Connection attempt failed with "EAI_NONAME - Neither nodename nor servname provided, or not known"

No such host is known

Host does not exist
```

I have searched extensively on this topic, both today and in the past and never found any solution that works.

Can anyone spot WTH I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I should be helpful if you look into the log file of the ftp client you use. IMHO this error is too general to be debugged.

Comment: You sure ftp.domain.com exists? can try to ping it or do port checking ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the error you are getting it is an issue with hostname. When setting up account with WHM ftp.domain.com DNS record might not have been created. So from cPanel > Advanced Zone Editor check if you have ftp.domain.com has A record of your server or not if not add ftp.domain.com to your DNS.

Sometimes Encryption can also cause issue but not the one you have described. So try the following:

```
Host: domain.com
User: account@domain.com
Port: 21
Protocol: FTP
Encryption: Only use plain FTP (insecure)
```

Comment: Godddddddammmmmmmnnnnnnnn that is the answer! I drop "ftp" off the front of the address (even though in the settings it says to include it) and magically it works. Have just tried this on two separate sites, and yep :O I can't believe that was such a simple answer to such a frustrating problem.